# Can I watch an ENS name like I can watch a token?

Tags: mist, parity-wallet, ens

When I buy an ERC20 token, I can 'watch' it with my Mist or Parity wallet. And, I don't have to go to any websites.

Is there a similar thing to do with an ENS name? I won four auctions a couple of months ago, but I can't figure out how to 'watch' them without going to a website.

When I go to the website (https://registrar.ens.domains/) with a parity-enabled browser, I do see my names, but I'm trying to live a fully decentralized life, which to me means no browsers and no https://. Does that even make sense?

Comment: Since you own the names, what do you want to "watch" them do?

Comment: Great question. I want to watch them continue to be mine. I'm like Golom stroking his precious.

Comment: Hah, ok. Well even creating a "Custom Contract" for ENS inside Mist is still using a Dapp loaded over https. So I read this as: "how can I load registrar.ens.domains or manager.ens.domains over swarm?" I'm not sure, so I'll delete my answer and let someone with more Swarm knowledge answer.

Comment: Maybe the question makes no sense. Don't delete your answer.

Comment: Also, are you sure you're right?  I'm pretty sure watching a contract is being served from a locally running node. Over http, but not over the internet.

Comment: Ok, undeleted. What I mean is that the Dapp that you are using to manage your wallets and contracts (which is made up of HTML and Javascript that is loaded in the Mist browser, and then connects to the web3 object that Mist exposes) is loaded over http. You are right that the request that loads the contract details is run on the local node. But the name info is also loaded locally when you use registrar.ens.domains with an appropriate browser like Mist, or Parity, or Chrome with Metamask. If this is what you were getting at, I'll update my answer with this ^.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Here's what I mean. I want to be able to sync my local node, then shut down the internet connection, then see my .eth names. I'm pretty sure I can do this and see my ERC tokens because the wallet is communicating only with the node. That is the question I was asking. How can I see my .eth names in a fully decentralized way.

Comment: So, I think you did actually answer my question. Give me a bump in a couple of days, and if no-one else answered better I'll select your answer.

Comment: Ok, I rewrote using the online/offline method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to follow the line of thought from the comments: let's load a Dapp while online, and interact with it offline.

**Online**

In Mist, load https://manager.ens.domains/

**Offline**

1. Authorize one of your accounts to interact with the page.
2. Search for a name you own
3. Look in the 'owner' field to see that your account still owns the name
4. *Congratulations, you still have your precious!* :P

Other than loading the dapp, everything else can be done offline.

Comment: For the more hardcore approach, you can download the ENS manager source and run it locally: https://github.com/jefflau/ens-manager/

Comment: I've been looking at this. I did download it, but I can't get it running yet, but this is along the lines of what I was thinking. I'm really trying to convince myself that there is a world with no browser, no web, just local blockchain node and local apps--the only data comes through a decentralized pathway. Maybe not possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the mechanics on your specific wallets but yeah the ens is an NFT so you can watch it.

There will be more advanced ways but even just setting an alert on the holding wallet for any transactions would be a start.